# Why do I get the error coercing to unicode: need string or buffer, int found

Tags: python

Get file from user

```
file = input("Please enter the data file you wish to open: ")
```

Get search value from user

```
value = int(input("Input a number to search for: "))
```

Open the file

```
datlist = open(file, "rb")
```

Read the lines in the file

```
FileNums = datlist.read().splitlines()
```

Close the file

```
datlist.close()
```

Comment: Please copy-paste the precise error message you get when you run the above script. On *my* machine, I cannot get the error message you imply in your question.

Comment: It would be nice if you could mark an answer if it helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

From the error I infer that use Python 2.x. In this case, use [`raw_input`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input), [`input` automatically evaluates the input as a Python statement](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input), which in your case means any number you type will be returned as an `int`, not a string.

Your example should work as is in Python 3.x, as [`input` was changed to return a `str`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) and `raw_input` removed.

Comment: It might help to provide a description of how `input()` changes from Python2 to Python3.

Answer (score 0):

First `File` is a reservedword in python. So you'd better not use it as a variable.
Here is a sample as a reference

```
#!/bin/python

filename = raw_input("Please enter the data file you wish to open: ")
value = raw_input("Input a number to search for: ")

fin = file(fin, "rb")

for lines in fin:
    line = lines.rstrip().split()
    if value in line:
       print line

fin.close()
```

Comment: The reserved keyword is `file`, not `File`.